# In SimpleSAMLPHP, using example-sql example-sql, how to define groups

Tags: simplesamlphp

During local development of a project which will eventually integrate with an outside SSO provider via SimpleSAMLPHP, I have used the "example-sql" authsource with some dummy users.

The example code:

```
'example-sql' => array(
    'sqlauth:SQL',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=sql.example.org;port=5432;dbname=simplesaml',
    'username' => 'simplesaml',
    'password' => 'secretpassword',
    'query' => 'SELECT uid, givenName, email, eduPersonPrincipalName FROM users WHERE uid = :username AND password = SHA2(CONCAT((SELECT salt FROM users WHERE uid = :username), :password),256);',
),
```

Does not show how to specify which groups a user belongs to. If I add a column to my MySQL database called attributes, and add to it, for a user, something like "eduPersonAffiliation:group_1,group_2", should that tell SimpleSAMLPHP that my user is in those groups?

Answer (score 1):

All selected columns in `query` will be available as attributes for your user.
So imagine you have a column `groups` it could represent you all groups the user is assigned (e.g. `group_1,group_2`)

As it's mentioned in simplesamlphp documentation you could also store the user/group assignment in an additional table

```
SELECT uid, ... , groupname AS groups
FROM users LEFT JOIN usergroups ON users.uid = usergroups.username
WHERE ...
```

see https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/sqlauth:sql